# Auth: (24) Login incorrect (No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject):

Tags: freeradius, radius

I'm migrating a functioning freeradius install version 2.2.8 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS to version 3.0.16 on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I setup daloradius this time.
I've setup my clients
I've setup my users
I deliver DSL and do auth and assign static IP addresses
I need radius to return the Framed-IP-Address attribute if required

This is all in mysql and I need accounting to be stored in mysql also.

So far I'm getting this:

```
 Auth: (24) Login incorrect (No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject): [test@xxx.xxxx.xx/!yyyyyyyy!] (from client 999.888.777.666 port 268439551 cli xxxxxxadsfad-47:621)
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.
G